# How do I create a persistent volume on an in-house kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I have a 3-node Kubernetes cluster running on vagrant using the oracle Kubernetes vagrant boxes from http://github.com/oracle/vagrant-boxes.git.

I want to add a pod including an Oracle database and persist the data so that in case all nodes go down, I don't lose my data.

According to how I read the Kubernetes documentation persistent volumes cannot be created on a local filesystem only on a cloud-backed device.  I want to configure the persistent volume and persistent volume claim on my vagrant boxes as a proof of concept and training exercise for my Kubernetes learning.

Are there any examples of how I might go about creating the PV and PVC in this configuration?

As a complete Kubernetes newbie, any code samples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use host path:

create PV:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: task-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data
```

create PVC:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: task-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

Use it in a pod:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: task-pv-pod
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: task-pv-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
       claimName: task-pv-claim
  containers:
    - name: task-pv-container
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: "http-server"
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
          name: task-pv-storage
```

[documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#create-a-persistentvolume)

This is just an example, for testing only.

For production use case, you will need dynamic provisioning using the  [StorageClass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/) for PVC, so that the volume/data is available when the pod moves across the cluster.

Comment: Be aware though that host path only works on the same node where your pod ends up scheduled. If it gets evicted from a node, for example and ends up on a different one it will be host path of that new node.